# Evento EditText.SelectionChanged no Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Preciso desse evento que tem no Windows Forms:

```
private void richTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Só que para Xamarin, no Android. Notem que não estou usando app cross-platform.

Consigo usar o evento `EditText_TextChanged` assim:

```
EditText editText;
...
editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText);
editText.TextChanged += editText_TextChanged;
```

Mas, quando digito `editText.OnSelectionChanged`, recebo o erro:

> EditText.OnSelectionChanged(int, int)' is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

Como faço para acessar esse evento?

Answer (score 1):

O método OnSelectionChanged é protegido, portanto ele só pode ser acessado por subclasses de EditText.

Crie uma subclasse de EditText sobrescrevendo o método e os construtores:

```
public class MyEditText : EditText {
    public MyEditText (Context context) : base(context) {
    }

    public MyEditText (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs) {
    }

    public MyEditText (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    }

    public MyEditText (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
    }

    protected MyEditText (IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) {
    }

    protected override void OnSelectionChanged (int selStart, int selEnd) { 
        base.OnSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
        //Sua lógica aqui
    }
}
```